# Using lapply to create a row with means of other rows

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes, and I need for each one create two new rows, that have the mean values of the first and last rows. For example

```
df1<-data.frame(
  Concentrations=c("10","5","2"),
  Value_1=c(5000, 4000,3000),
  Value_2=c(4000,6000,2000)
)
df2<-data.frame(
  Concentrations=c("10","5","2"),
  Value_1=c(3000, 9000,2000), 
  Value_2=c(5000,8000,2000)
)
list.df<-list(df1,df2)
```

For that I would need a fourth row where all the values would be 4000, and a fifth one, where would be 2.500.
I am guessing that my best bet would be using the lapply function, but how should I proceed?

Comment: Can you also provide a sample of desired output--i.e. what the final data should look like? I'm not sure which values you want averaged and where you want them placed, so seeing sample output should clear that up.

Comment: Do you need `lapply(list.df, \(x) {x[nrow(x) +1, -1] <- colMeans(x[c(1, nrow(x)), -1]); x})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if that goes in the direction of what you have had in mind, however, maybe it helps!

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
  purrr::map(list.df, ~ add_row(.data = .x,
    Value_1 = (first(.x$Value_1) + last(.x$Value_1)) / 2,
    Value_2 = (first(.x$Value_1) + last(.x$Value_1)) / 2
  ))
```

Creates:

```
[[1]]
  Concentrations Value_1 Value_2
1             10    5000    4000
2              5    4000    6000
3              2    3000    2000
4           <NA>    4000    4000

[[2]]
  Concentrations Value_1 Value_2
1             10    3000    5000
2              5    9000    8000
3              2    2000    2000
4           <NA>    2500    2500
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, both answers from Julian and akrun helped me a lot to do what I needed.